# Layout preview is different than layout on device on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I have a problem with my app layout on nexus 7 device (tvdpi), the preview on eclipse (that is how i wold my app looks like) is dirrent than layout on real device. In fact, on device a small drawable is used instead correct one. This is my drawable and layout folders

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-tvdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- layout
- layout-xhdpi
- layout-xxhdpi

i don't have layout folders for each screen type because i don't need for all (most of layout is composed by images).
This is one of my layout that on real device doesn't appear like preview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

what's wrong? drawables are scaled correctly.

Comment: Not an answer - but have you tried using the native ADT emulator or something like genymotion?

Comment: no. But i can't understand why preview use correct drawable, but real device use smaller one (i think it use mdpi drawables)

Comment: is the screen resolution selected in the emulator exactly same as the screen of the real device? the difference has caused me pain before.

Comment: I don't run app on emulator. I'm just see graphical preview on eclipse editor!

Comment: And at the top of that graphical preview in eclipse there's a selection box of which device it's displaying ... which means there's a certain resolution it's using

Comment: i know. The screen type selected is correct